# How to search products by title using Shopify product search API?

Tags: api, shopify

We have created a Shopify app in which user can search for products of his own store by typing first 3 characters of product title. Products will be shown in a dropdown based on his search.

Now the problem is, how we can enable the search system to search directly from product search api?
We checked product search api on shopify but information is limited.

Can anyone help in this please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What is your actual problem? There is no search API, so what are you trying to accomplish? Sounds like you are confused about something. More details would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple, make your api call thus:

```
GET /admin/products.json?title=your_product_title
```